# Як відмінюються складні (іншомовні) імена як-то Жан-Жак, Еріх-Марія?

Tags: власні-назви, відмінювання

Яке правило керує відмінюванням складених імен (переважно іншомовних)? Наскільки я розумію, теоретично є три варіанти:

1. Відмінюється лише перше слово: *Жаном-Жак*, *Еріхом-Марія*
2. Відмінюється лише друге (останнє) слово:  *Жан-Жаком*, *Еріх-Марією*
3. Відмінюються обидва:  *Жаном-Жаком*, *Еріхом-Марією*

Правопис згадує [написання через дефіс чи окремо](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par106), а також правопис **прикметників**. Але нічого не каже про відмінювання **іменників**.

Попереднє дослідження показало суцільну суперечність у джерелах:

1. За перший варіант:

   [Ґуґлопошук "еріх**ом**+марі**я**+ремарком"](https://www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC"&lr=lang_uk)

   > Він мріяв познайомитись із, на той час живими лише в книгах, Ернестом Гемінгвеєм, [Еріх**ом** Марі**я** Ремарком](https://day.kyiv.ua/uk/article/taym-aut/pismenniki-zminyuyut-profesiyu), Редьярдом Кіплінгом
2. За другий варіант:

   [Ґуґлопошук "жа**н**+жак**ом**"](https://www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC"&lr=lang_uk)

   > [Реферат - Теорія суспільного договору за Жа**н**-Жак**ом** Руссо](http://referatu.net.ua/referats/68/39388)
   >
   > [«Безтямний П'єро»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9F%27%D1%94%D1%80%D0%BE) — французько-італійська кримінальна драма 1965 року, поставлена режисером Жа**н**-Люк**ом** Годаром […] з Жа**н**-Пол**ем** Бельмондо […]
3. За третій варіант:

   [Ґуґлопошук "жан**ом**+жак**ом**"](https://www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC"&lr=lang_uk)
   [Ґуґлопошук "еріх**ом**+марі**єю**+ремарком"](https://www.google.com/search?q="%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%94%D1%8E+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC"&lr=lang_uk)

> Свій 92-й сезон він відзначив соковитою прем’єрою – виставою «Троє товаришів» [за Еріх**ом**-Марі**єю** Ремарком](http://visitlviv.net/news/ua/remark-v-teatri-zankoveckoi/).

Отже, запитання:
**Яке правило керує відмінюванням складених імен (переважно іншомовних)?**

Answer (score 2):

У ["Діловій українській мові" І. Плотницької](http://subject.com.ua/pdf/48.html) (с.55) надано принцип відмінювання складних особових імен, що являють собою поєднання двох самостійних прізвищ:

> Складені чоловічі та жіночі прізвища, що становлять поєднання двох
>   самостійних прізвищ, відмінюються за правилами відмінювання кожної
>   складової частини: Іван Чулюк-Заграй, Івана Чулюка-Заграя, Іванові
>   Чулюку-Заграю...

Цей принцип діє і щодо відмінювання імен. Отже, правильно Жана-Жака, Еріха-Марії, так само, як відмінюються складені особові імена слов'янського походження Зиновій-Богдан - Зиновія-Богдана, Василь-Костянтин - Василя-Костянтина. Але Франсуа-Батиста, Шарля-Луї і т.п. (одна з частин є невідмінюваною).